# count digits white space and others in C

Tags: c

I am trying to do an exercise from [The C programming Language](http://alvand.basu.ac.ir/~dezfoulian/files/Programming/Prentice%20Hall%20-%20The%20C%20Programming%20Language-%20Brian%20W.%20Kernighan,%20Dennis%20M.%20Ritchie,%202nd%20ed.,%20ISBN%20.pdf) and I am having some issues with it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* count digits, white space, others */
main()
{
    int c, i, nwhite, nother;
    int ndigit[10];
    nwhite = nother = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        ndigit[i] = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c >= ’0’ && c <= ’9’)
        ++ndigit[c - ’0’];
        else if (c == ’ ’ || c == ’\n’ || c == ’\t’)
            ++nwhite;
        else
            ++nother;
        printf("digits =");
        for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
        printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n",
            nwhite, nother);
}
```

Error:

```
E:\Files\C\main.c:3:1: warning: return type defaults to 'int' [-Wreturn-type]

E:\Files\C\main.c:11:9: error: stray '\222' in program
```

Comment: Where's the C++ part of the question?

Comment: Please, indent your code. This is unpleasant to my eyes

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you give us a sample input and desired output?

Comment: Also you have no brackets around your loops. Is this intentional? If it isn't then your code won't work correctly because it will only loop the line just after the loop decleration

Comment: Additionally, I would like to introduce you to this character '{' and this one '}'. They're super helpful in making your loops work as intended while making your code SO much more readable.

Comment: It is not my code but it is taken from book written by K and R i tried to compile as is what is given in that pdf and it failed :O

Comment: What error are you getting? That would be helpful.

Comment: most probably `if (c >= ’0’ && c <= ’9’)` should be `if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')` and likewise for other cases.

Comment: Also I suggest you use `isdigit()` and `isspace()` rather than comparing characters directly.

Comment: Thanks Sourav Now it works

Comment: `int main(void) { ... }` or `int main(int argc, char **argv) { ... }`

Comment: Why are you using the C++ tag when the question title is C, and the book is about the C language?

Comment: `(c == ’ ’ || c == ’\n’ || c == ’\t’)` only counts some of the characters that  could be a white-space.  Recommend `isspace()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly what you're trying to achieve, but I think this is what you're wanting (also as other have said, always use {}, it makes code much easier to read. there's times where technically you don't need to, such as 1 conditional after an if statement, but even then I still do it for readability):

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* count digits, white space, others */
int main()
{
    int c, i, nwhite, nother;
    int ndigit[10];
    nwhite = nother = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        ndigit[i] = 0;
    }

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        {
            ++ndigit[c - '0'];
        }
        else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
        {
            ++nwhite;
        }
        else
            ++nother;

        printf("digits =");
        for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
        }
        printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n",
            nwhite, nother);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This has to deal with ASCII VALUES.

For Example. If you enter 3 as input

getchar() returns value 51 which is ascii value of 3

so we have c with 51 and the ASCII value of 0 is 48.
so
c-'0'=51-48=3
so you will get expression ndigit[3]=ndigit[3]+1, thus increasing the value of counting digit 3 input

Answer (score 0):

Function `main` lacks type (usually `int` or `void`).
Also, using curly braces and indentation makes your code more readable, thus easier to find the mistakes.

Comment: nopes. adding a `return` value in `main()` is not a mandate, purely optional.

Comment: wow, didn't know that non-void functions don't need return command, thanks for correction...however, isn't that only in C99?

Answer (score 0):

I copied and pasted your code into my text editor and then compiled it and then got the same error you were receiving, so you're not alone, which is fantastic news. Luckily, I was able to fix it. The issue is arising from these three lines of code:

```
      if (c >= ’0’ && c <= ’9’)
```

and

```
      ++ndigit[c - ’0’];
```

and

```
       else if (c == ’ ’ || c == ’\n’ || c == ’\t’)
```

I was able to fix this issue by changing the single quotation marks.  For example, when I use the correct apostrophe, the if loop looks like:

```
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
```

As for corrections, that's it! Your code should run perfectly after you fix those apostrophes. And as a parting note, when you do get it to compile and run, look up what the EOF is on your operating system. On mine (Ubuntu) I use CTRL+d. Good luck to you!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c, ns, nt, nn;
        ns = nt = nn =0;
    while( (c = getchar()) != EOF) {

        if ( c == ' ') {
            ++ns;
        } else if (c == '\t') {
            ++nt;
        } else if (c == '\n') {
            ++nn;
        }
  }
printf("Space: %d, Tab: %d, NewLine: %d\n\n", ns,nt,nn);
}
```

Compile and run program. For exit enter Ctrl-D and view count inputs whitespaces, tabs and newlines.